# How to iterate over MultiPartfile[] in spring framework

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a java application, which has a directory with XML files(student information), I parse them to a single list as shown below

Student.java

```
import java.util.List;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import lombok.Data;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student{
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String gender;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Address")    
    @XmlElement(name="address")
    private List<String> address;
    
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Subjects")   
    @XmlElement(name="subjects") 
    private List<String> subjects;
}
```

I create a list of students by loading all the studentXmls as shown below:

```
List<Student> listOfStudents = loadBaseNodesets();


 private static List<Student> loadBaseNodesets() throws JAXBException {
      
        log.info("Loading nodesets");
        Student xmlentries = null;
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        List<UANodeSet> xmlEntriesList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> privateBaseNodeSets= new ArrayList<>();
        File dir = new File("src/main/resources/XMLFiles");
        if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
            
            FileFilter filter = (File file) -> file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xml");
        log.info("iterating through all files");
        File [] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
        if (files != null) {                    
                for (int i =0;i <files.length;i++) {    
                    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
                    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                    xmlentries = (Student) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(files[i]);
                    privateBaseNodeSets.add(xmlentries.toString());
                    log.info(files[i].getName()+" loaded");
                    xmlEntriesList.add(xmlentries); 
                }
            }       
        }       
        log.info("Nodeset loading complete");
    return xmlEntriesList;
  }
```

Here, I have stored my XMLs in a directory and I can make use of the path.
But, we are migrating to microservices, with Spring framework. I should not be storing it anywhere. It should be passed using the endpoint through postman, and the parameter should be used to parse it to list of Students..
I have made use of a code below:

```
 @PostMapping(path ="/uploadFiles")
    public ResponseEntity<String> fileUpload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException{

List<Student> students= loadBaseNodesets(files); //here i am struggling to establish the logic
    
}
```

I have passed the files through the endpoint, and I want to parse it to a list of Students

```
List<Student> listOfStudents = loadBaseNodesets(files); //multipart files
```

Any suggestion as to how can this be done?

Comment: What do you want to do with `MultipartFile[] files`?

Comment: i want all the files that I put into ```MultipartFile[] files``` to be parsed to a list of Students..```List<Student>listOfStudents```

Comment: @navnath please see the edit

Comment: Check if this helps you [How to read XML file in Java – DOM Parser](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)